# After setting focusPointOfInterest AVCaptureOutput stops how to start?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

We are setting focusPointOfInterest but just after AVCaptureOutput stops although on iPhone screen we can still see live camera feed.

We could not find the reason and how to solve.

We are using SwiftUI by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Are you locking/unlocking your device for configuration? Something like this usually works for me:

```
func setFocusPointOfInterest(device: AVCaptureDevice, focusPoint: CGPoint) throws {
    if !device.isFocusPointOfInterestSupported ||
        !device.isFocusModeSupported(.autoFocus) || 
        device.isAdjustingFocus || 
        device.isAdjustingExposure {
        return
    }
    try device.lockForConfiguration()
    device.focusPointOfInterest = focusPoint
    device.focusMode = .autoFocus
    device.unlockForConfiguration()
}
```